# Displaying data in a different way

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a log table that looks like this:

```
ProductId | OldDescription | NewDescription | OldTagId | NewTagId |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
12345     |  description1  |  description2  |     1    |      5   |
```

and I want to display it this way:

```
ProductId | ChangeId     |      OldVal    |    NewVal    | 
----------------------------------------------------------
12345     |      1       |  description1  | description2 |
12345     |      2       |       1        |      5       |
```

Where the data in the ChangeId corresponds to the type of the value changed (Description, TagId)

How could I approach this?

Thank you

Comment: I really recommend you stick with the original format. You're mixing datatypes in the latter, and that's a bad idea.

Comment: You can use an XML field or string field containing JSON as a bag to store extra data. The EAV schema you show in the second example is a rather bad idea - hard to query, hard to modify, impossible to validate, very slow to use as indexes become useless

Comment: Are you saying you want that as the result of a query, or you want to change your table structure?

Comment: I only need it as result of a query @EricBrandt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just another option via CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ProductId] varchar(50),[OldDescription] varchar(50),[NewDescription] varchar(50),[OldTagId] int,[NewTagId] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (12345,'description1','description2',1,5)

Select ProductID 
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (1,[OldDescription],[NewDescription])
                     ,(2,left([OldTagId],25),left([NewTagId],25))
             ) B(ChangeID,OldVal,NewVal)
```

**Returns**

```
ProductID   ChangeID    OldVal          NewVal
12345       1           description1    description2
12345       2           1               5
```

**Just for fun:**

I saw the comment of 30 columns.  If performance is NOT essential, here is option that will dynamically pivot your data without actually using dynamic SQL

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select ProductID 
              ,C.*
         From  @YourTable A
         Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
         Cross Apply (
                        Select Item      = left(xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)'),3)+'Val'
                              ,Value     = xAttr.value('.','varchar(100)')
                              ,ChangeID  = ((row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 ) / 2)+1
                         From  XMLData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
                         Where xAttr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('ProductID','Other','ColumnsToExclude')
                     ) C
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(Value) for Item in ([OldVal],[NewVal]) ) pvt
```

Comment: @bapster See my "Just for Fun" option

Answer (score 0):

See if something like that works for you:

```
SELECT ProductId,
       1              AS ChangeId,
       OldDescription AS OldVal,
       NewDescription AS NewVal
FROM   log
UNION
SELECT ProductId,
       2        AS ChangeId,
       OldTagId AS OldVal,
       NewTagId AS NewVal
FROM   log
ORDER  BY ProductId,
          ChangeId
```

Comment: What for multiple product IDs with the multiple change value?

Comment: This will fail assuming that OldTagId and NewTagId are integers. It would attempt an implicit conversion and fail.

Comment: Thats the way I've approached it casting the OldVal/NewVal to a VARCHAR type and that works fine for 2 columns, but what if I have to deal with 30 columns? I guess there's some other way than typing it all for 30 separate columns

Comment: @bapster If you had already tried something then you should always include that in your question and describe why you do not want this?

Comment: @bapster if you have 30 columns you have to code for them all. Sounds like you have some normalization issues in your log table.

Comment: @SeanLange Well, I actually only have 2 columns just as described in the question. Just looking for some different way of solving it